# How to specify this query using Squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel, squeel

Suppose I have a model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base   
   attr_accessible :title  # it has title attribute   
   has_many :pictures 
end
```

I want to define a `scope` query called `completed` that:

> Returns all questions whose:
>
> - title is not empty 
>     OR
> - has at least 1 picture

How can I do that?

So far, I have:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base   
   attr_accessible :title  # it has title attribute   
   has_many :pictures 

   scope :completed, where{title != ""}  # returns all questions with non-empty title
end
```

It'd be nice if I could just say:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base   
   attr_accessible :title  # it has title attribute   
   has_many :pictures 

   scope :completed, where{title != "" || pictures.count > 0}
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can do this with Squeel! Just write your scope this way:

```
scope :completed, joins{pictures.outer}.where{(title != "") | (pictures.id != nil)}.group{id}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Would this query return me all the Questions that _either_ have 1) title **or** 2) at least 1 picture? Or is this query saying "returns Questions that has a title **and** have at least one picture?"

Comment: I'm looking for a query that will do the first one. That is, questions that either have a title, **or** at least a picture.

Comment: sorry for that I misunderstood the question. You need an outer join. I posted the right squeel now :)!

Comment: thanks so much! Btw, why is it necessary to call group at the end?

Comment: This is because the Question has many pictures and with the group at the end you are ensuring the non-duplication of the question rows!